# Roots of unity - sum over all the solutions is zero?

Tags: summation, roots

> Show that for all roots of unity $z\neq 1$, meaning solutions of the equation $z^n=1$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}$ the following is true:
>
> $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}z^k=0$.

I'm totally lost here. I thought I would do this by induction, but I can't even find a solution to the equation besides 1.

Comment: The usual trick is to realize that the roots of unity are the roots of the polynomial $z^n -1$, and therefore the sum of the roots is the same as (minus) the coefficient on $z^{n-1}$.

Comment: Use Vieta's theorem for a quick solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note That if $z=e^{2 \pi i/n}$ is a root, we have $z^n=1$

We have the following equality: $z^0 + z + z^2 + \ldots + z^{n-1} = \frac{z^{n}-1}{z-1} = 0$ because $z^n-1 = 1-1 = 0$

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that $\frac{z^n-1}{z-1}$ was the solution to that series. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

we have

$z(1+z+z^2+....z^{n-1})=z.S$

$=z+z^2+.......+z^{n-1}+1=S$

thus $S=zS$ and $S=0$ since $z\neq 0$ and $z\neq 1.$